# Cannot detect keypress when using TNotifyEvent in a custom control

Tags: delphi

I have a custom control derived from `TCustomListBox` and I am trying to override the `OnKeyDown` method within my components source.

The problem I have run into is when using my component I cannot detect what key has been pressed. The parameter `var Key: Word;` appears to have become redundant, so I am not sure if I am doing this the correct way or not which might explain my problem.

Here is a stripped down source example:

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  private
    FOnClick: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnKeyDown: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnMouseDown: TNotifyEvent;
  protected
    procedure Click; override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnClick write FOnClick;
    property OnKeyDown: TNotifyEvent read FOnKeyDown write FOnKeyDown;
    property OnMouseDown: TNotifyEvent read FOnMouseDown write FOnMouseDown;
  end;

implementation

constructor TMyListBox.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  OnClick := FOnClick;
  OnKeyDown := FOnKeyDown;
  OnMouseDown := FOnMouseDown;
end;

destructor TMyListBox.Destroy;
begin
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TMyListBox.Click();
begin
  inherited;

  // do something

  if Assigned(FOnClick) then
    FOnClick(Self);
end;

procedure TMyListBox.KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;

  // do something

  if Assigned(FOnKeyDown) then
    FOnKeyDown(Self);
end;

procedure TMyListBox.MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  inherited;

  // do something

  if Assigned(FOnMouseDown) then
    FOnMouseDown(Self);
end;
```

When trying my component in a regular project:

```
procedure TForm1.MyListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_DELETE then
  begin
    ShowMessage('test'); // never triggers
  end;
end;
```

I think it may be something to do with how I am overriding the event? The standard declaration for a listbox keydown looks like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListBox1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  //
end;
```

The difference is the `Sender` parameter but I dont and cant use that in my component source.

So I guess I want to know why I cannot detect the key pressed, and whether I should be overriding the methods in a different/better way?

Thanks.

Comment: So you are trying to make your own `OnKeyDown` and `OnMouseDown` events of type `TNotifyEvent`, but in your project you are expecting them to be of type `TKeyEvent` and `TMouseEvent` ? Or what is the problem ?

Comment: Just have a look at the source of `TListBox` and learn from it :o)

Comment: @TLama when you put it like that it does seem rather odd what I was doing, I just dont always recognise the problem until either later on someone points it out to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnKeyDown`, `OnKeyUp`, and `OnKeyPress` are not `TNotifyEvents`.

`OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp` are `TKeyEvent`, and `OnKeyPress` is a `TKeyPressEvent`.

`TNotifyEvent` is defined as

```
type
  TNotifyEvent = procedure (Sender: TObject) of object;
```

`TKeyEvent` and `TKeyPressEvent` are defined as follows:

```
type
  TKeyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
    Shift: TShiftState) of object;
  TKeyPressEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char) of object;
```

So if you declare `FOnKeyDown` as type `TNotifyEvent`, the only parameter it can accept is `Sender: TObject`. If you want it to accept the same parameters as `TKeyEvent`, then declare it as `TKeyEvent`. The same applies to `TMouseEvent` and `OnClick`.

Or, better yet, just promote them to published from the ancestor, as they're already declared as protected in `TCustomListBox`:

```
type
  TMyListBox = class(TCustomListBox)
  protected
    procedure Click; override;
    procedure KeyDown(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState); override;
    procedure MouseDown(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property OnClick;
    property OnKeyDown;
    property OnMouseDown;
  end;
```

`Sender` will automatically be provided for you; it's the component that triggered the event. So in an `OnClick` handler for a `TButton`, `Sender` will be the button that was clicked. You don't have any choice whether to receive it or not; the VCL will do so. You can choose not to use it, but you're going to get it (and have to declare your procedure as receiving it) whether you want to or not.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks your help and input Ken :) I want to apologise though for the other week as I probably spoke aggressively or rude to you, so no hard feelings? :-)

Comment: Great :) well I see now what I was doing wrong especially after TLama's comment. basically I was turning the correctly defined keyboard and mouse events into a standard event, so as you said in your answer I just removed all the TNotifyEvent stuff and changed the published methods like: `property OnClick;`